# Basic theorem from vector analysis - Condition that 4 points $A,B,C,D$ no three of which are collinear, will lie in a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, vectors

I am taking a first course in Vector calculus. I am attempting to write a proof for the following theorem.

The proof in the book splits this into two cases -

(i) either the $\vec {AB}$ is parallel to $\vec {CD}$, so $\vec {AB} = k \cdot\vec{CD}$

(ii) $\vec {AB}$ intersects $\vec {CD}$ at some point $P$, so $p=\frac{a+\lambda b}{1+\lambda}=\frac{c+\lambda' d}{1+\lambda'}$

Although I know the section formula, I couldn't come up with the above formulation on my own. The below is my proof. Could someone comment, on whether the proof is elegant, and also acceptable?

> **Theorem.** *Four points $A,B,C,D,$ no three of which are collinear, will lie in a plane when and only when there exist four non-zero numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,$ such that*
>
> $$\alpha a+ \beta b + \gamma c + \delta d = 0 \\
>   \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = 0 $$

**Proof.**

*Idea: If the four points are coplanar, we should be able to construct a parallelogram of the diagonal on $\vec{CD}$, with sides as scalar multiples of $\vec {AB}$ and $\vec {CD}$.*

Let

$\begin{aligned}
\vec {CD} &= \lambda \vec{AB} + \lambda' \vec{BC}\\
(d - c) &= \lambda (b - a) + \lambda'(c - b)\\
d &= -\lambda a + (\lambda - \lambda')b + (1 + \lambda')c
\end{aligned}$

We would like the coefficients of $a,b,c$ to be $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ respective.

Set : $-\lambda = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma},
1+\lambda' = \frac{\gamma}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}$. Solving for $\lambda,\lambda'$ we get :

$$\begin{aligned}
\lambda' &= -\frac{(\alpha + \beta)}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}\\
\lambda - \lambda' &= \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}
\end{aligned}$$

So, we have :

$$\begin{aligned}
d &= \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}a + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}b + \frac{\gamma}{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}c \\\\
(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)d &= \alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c
\end{aligned}$$

Let $\delta = -(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)$. Thus,

$$
\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c + \delta d = 0
$$

Further, these constants are non-zero, since $\lambda,\lambda'$ cannot be $0,\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The proof in the book splits this into two cases

Don't quite follow this. There is just *two* cases only if the points are assumed to be coplanar already. Otherwise, it is entirely possible that $AB$ and $CD$ are skew i.e. neither parallel, nor intersecting.

The more direct way, in my opinion, would be to rewrite it in the equivalent form:

> **Theorem.** Four points $A,B,C,D,$ no three of which are collinear, will lie in a plane when and only when there exist ***three*** non-zero numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\,,$ ***with*** $\alpha+\beta+\gamma \ne 0\,$ such that
>   $$\alpha a+ \beta b + \gamma c - (\alpha+\beta+\gamma) d = 0$$

This reduces to:

$$
d= \frac{\alpha a+ \beta b + \gamma c}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma} = a + \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}(b-a) + \frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}(c-a) \\[20px]
 \iff\quad\quad d-a = \lambda (b-a) + \mu(c-a)
$$

The latter means $\vec{AD}$ is a linear combination of $\vec{AB}$ and $\,\vec{AC}\,$, which is the necessary and sufficient condition for the points to be coplanar.

Comment: The proof in the book starts with those two possibilities. I have listed my proof however - beginning with the basic idea, the it should be possible to construct a parallelogram with diagonal as $\vec{CD}$ and sides $\lambda \vec{AB}$ and $\mu \vec{BC}$ - triangle law of addition.

Comment: @Quasar I didn't say it didn't ;-) Just that I don't understand *their* reasoning. Neither of those possibilities covers the case where $AB,CD$ are the opposite edges of a tetrahedron, for example.

Comment: Yes, I meant *coplanar*! Corrected the typo.

Comment: Sorry, about being outright careless, while representing my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3$ be the points. Then all four points are on the same plane if array whos rows are the coordinates of $x_1-x_0, x_2-x_0, x_3-x_0$ has a rank of two.